# auto check in the files uploaded on Sharepoint using batch file

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint

Could you please help me to upload files and auto check in on Share Point through batch script from windows server?
Whenever I try to upload files on SP thorough batch files, the script is automatically checked out and it is invisible to other users except me, so I need to check in every time manually.

Comment: you can use `net use` to connect to the share using the same credentials. Can you try connecting from cmdline and see if it words?

Comment: this is already in use for uploading file in share point.

Comment: ok, then what errors are you experiencing?

Comment: FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
    NET USE %SHAREPOINT_MOUNT% /DELETE

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        TIMEOUT %WAIT_PERIOD%
    ) ELSE (
        EXIT
    )
)
But with this the uploaded file in SP is getting chcked out automatically, so SP admin disabled Checkin/Checkout in the library as of now.
But we have to add the code for auto check in the files after uploading so that others can see the file.

Answer (score -1):

Use PowerShell with SharePoint Client Object Model (CSOM). Ask your favorite search engine, there are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: We cant use PS here, as all the codes are written on batch for more than 10 envs.We have to use batch here.

Comment: As far as i know you have to options then:
1. Disable Checkin/Checkout on the Library
2. Call a PowerShell Script from your batch script

Comment: right now , We have chosen option 1. but the SP admin already asked to check the possibility for auto check in of the files from batch itself.

Comment: We can opt for Option 2 as well, as SP admin is not going to disable Checkin/Checkout on the library for a longer period of time.As this will be breaching some internal policies.

Comment: Could you please help me in coding, how to call a PS from batch and what are the params we need to provide in PS?

Comment: The question is specific. How to check using "Batch File"